# I can't Access my internal Hard drive through shortcut applet of cairo dock

Tags: 11.10, gnome, cairo-dock

After upgrading from Ubuntu 11.04 to Ubuntu 11.10 I can't access my internal hard drive through the shortcut applet in Cairo-dock.

Whenever I try to open, banshee music player opens instead.

How can i fix this?

Comment: I dont understand: if cairo dock does NOT show an icon for your harddrive, what do you do when you want to open it?

Answer (score 1):

How apps are linked to the types of files (aka mimetypes) is defined in the .desktop files, in ~/.local/share/applications
It's completely broken in the 11.10, try to see if you can fix it by editing the nautilus.desktop file or the banshee.desktop file, or the mimeapps.list file.
I'm sorry, I had the same problem but I don't remember the exact way I could fix it, but it was by modifying one of these files.